# Install libmcrypt.dll on PHP 4.4.9 with windows 2008 server and IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis, dll, mcrypt

I need to enable mcrypt module on PHP 4.4.9. running on Windows 2008 Server and IIS 7.5.

I have uncommented php.ini line, but i get one message about 'libmcrypt.dll' file missing.

I have found two versions of this file searching on google. Downloaded, copied on the same folder of 'php.exe' file, and seems working. But sometimes, web site return:

```
HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway

The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of     HTTP headers. The headers it did return are "".

Error Code 0xc0000005
```

¿Where i can download the correct libmcrypt.dll file?

**Update**:
I have installed php 4.4.9 with the .zip package. Because i have others php versions in the same server. Running php as a cgi module configured on FastCGI Settings to run php.exe file.
PHP API: 20020918
PHP EXTENSION: 20020429

Comment: Maybe you can download it from apachefriends.org older xampp is still downloadable from sourceforge

Comment: Thanks @Mazaka. I have downloaded some xampp versiones and not seems to include this file.

Comment: in [this version](http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Windows/1.7.3/xampp-win32-1.7.3.zip) for example there is a php_mcrypt.dll that might work but i dont know forsure

Comment: [this version](http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Windows/1.6.3/xampp-win32-upgrade-1.6.2-1.6.3.zip) has a libmcrypt.dll in the php folder but the php version is still 5 so dont know if it works

Comment: php_mcrypt.dll file is included with php installation package for windows. The problem is that this file use another file (libmcrypt.dll) that is not included on php installation packages, and i don't know where i can get them.

Comment: @Mazaka, i have downloaded your proposed version (1.6.2-1.6.3) and don't work. Thanks

Comment: You should seriously consider upgrading your PHP version. If you are installing mcrypt for security purposes, your team are living in a dangerous illusion. This version [hasn't been updated since 2008](http://php.net/eol.php) Oo

Comment: RandomSeed, we have a lot of web pages developed on php 4.0 and can't afford the cost of update them to php 5.0.

Many of our pages use a payment system by credit card and the bank has changed the cipher. So I need to use mcrypt and have it running in a week. This is no time to update the version of PHP. But I appreciate the advice.